# fill_between with matplotlib and a where condition of two lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to shade the area before the point of intersection of the two curves produced by this example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(0,100,10)
y1 = [0,2,4,6,8,5,4,3,2,1]
y2 = [0,1,3,5,6,8,9,12,13,14]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t_list,y1,linestyle='-')
ax.plot(t_list,y2,linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Simply using:

```
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2,where=y1>=y2,color='grey',alpha='0.5')
```

Does no work and gives the following error: "ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible"

I tried to convert the lists into arrays:

```
z1 = np.array(y1)
z2 = np.array(y2)
```

Then:

```
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2,where=z1>=z2,color='grey',alpha='0.5')
```

Not the entire area was shaded.

I know I have to find the point of intersection between the two curves by interpolating but have not seen a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are completely right, you need to interpolate. And that is  ludicrously complicated, as you need to add the `interpolate=True` keyword argument to the call to `fill_between`.

```
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2,where=z1>=z2,color='grey', interpolate=True)
```

[image]

Complete code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(0,100,10)
y1 = [0,2,4,6,8,5,4,3,2,1]
y2 = [0,1,3,5,6,8,9,12,13,14]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y1,linestyle='-')
ax.plot(x,y2,linestyle='--')

z1 = np.array(y1)
z2 = np.array(y2)

ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2,where=z1>=z2,color='grey',alpha=0.5, interpolate=True)

plt.show()
```